# matrix function onto and 1-1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have just started a linear algebra paper and we are doing 1-1 and onto functions. I understand in theory what they mean, I just don't know how to prove them.

For example:

Define $f: M_2(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R} \text{ by } f(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d \end{bmatrix})=b$

Show that this is onto (or not) and 1-1 (or not)

****Edit****

So I'm a bit confused about what it means for $f(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d \end{bmatrix})=b$. How does a matrix equal a single value?

Comment: Are you sure that you understand "in theory what they mean"? If so this ought to be a straightforward exercise. Prove either by showing that the definition applies or finding a counterexample.

Comment: I think I am having more of a problem doing it with matrices than other functions, like I can do it with polynomials and stuff. I don't really understand what it means for the matrix to equal a single value...maybe I'll include that in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints** (straight from the definitions):

Consider any arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Are we guaranteed a matrix $M$ such that $f(M) = x?$  If so, then $f$ is onto.

Next, let's say $f(M) = x$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Is $M$ the *only* matrix such that $f(M) = x$?  If so, then $f$ is one-to-one.

---

**Edit** to respond to OP edit:

The function is taking matrices and mapping them to constants.  It's perfectly valid.  Go back to your original definition of a function.  A function is a relation between two sets: inputs and outputs such that each input has a unique output.  As far as the inputs and output sets are concerned -- they can be anything.  Here, the inputs are a set of matrices, and the outputs are a set of numbers, namely the real numbers.

Note that this is a function because, for any given matrix, you are going to get a unique output.  Now, perhaps it's not a very useful function, and that's kind of the point.  It's simply an exercise to check your understanding of one-to-one/onto in a slightly more abstract setting.

Comment: how does $f(M)$ equal a single value though? I think that's what I'm struggling with here

Comment: That's how the function is defined.  This is just some arbitrary function that is assigning each element in this set of matrices to an output in the set of real numbers.

Comment: Okay right, I think I got it, thanks!

Comment: @panderson, I'm glad I could help.  I had similar problems at one point.  I originally thought of functions as nothing more than something that you graph on the $xy$-plane because those are usually the only types of functions you encounter prior to linear algebra.  In major-level math courses, you'll encounter all sorts of weird functions, and most of them aren't what we're used to from before.